# subversion, check which file is not a certain revision

Tags: svn

First my English is poor. please understand me.

My problem is some file has different revision number with other files. and I want to know those file name.

For example, I updated only a.txt file to revision Number 3(actually I don't remember revision number exactly), but all the other files have revision number 2.

I want to know what file I had updated..   in this case, the answer is a.txt file.

Thanks in advance.

ps. I'm not sure if this command is exist :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> svn status -v

This will print (among many other things) for every file the working copy revision number and the latest server-side revision number.

Looks [like this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html):

```
 M            965       938 sally        wc/bar.c
        *     965       922 harry        wc/foo.c
A  +          965       687 harry        wc/qax.c
              965       687 harry        wc/zig.c
```

Comment: That's cool. I think I can get result source from that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

try `svn stat -u`. The documentation says:

> With --show-updates (-u), it adds working revision and server out-of-date information.